# How to put solutions of mutiple DEs with NDSolve in table

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, numerical-integration, programming

I have $N$ differential equation for each $s \in {1,2,...,N}$ on the domain $x \in [1,2]$ of the form (e.g.)

$xf_s'(x) + \log(xs) f_s(x)+1 = 0$, with the boundary condition $f_s(1) = e^{-s}$

Now I want to solve this equation with NDSolve. Put the values for the solutions at $x = 2$, i.e. $f_s(2)$ in a table enumerated by the index $s$. Then I want to interpolate between these values in the table to get a function $g(s) = f_s(2)$.

However, since I am new to mathematica, I have no Idea how to do this. I can solve the equation for some $s$ with NDSolve:

`NDSolve[{x*D[f[x], x] + Log[x*s]*f[x] + 1 == 0, f[1] == Exp[-s]}, f, {x, 1, 2}]`

and this seems to work. However my main issue right now is putting the values of the output function in the table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 100(* the number of equation,N*);
sols = {};(*table*)
 Do[
  AppendTo[sols, 
   f[2] /. Last@
     NDSolve[{x*D[f[x], x] + Log[x*s]*f[x] + 1 == 0, f[1] == Exp[-s]},
       f, {x, 1, 2}]],
  {s, 1, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

=>

```
{0.144813, Null}
```

```
sols // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Clear[s, f, sol];
sol = DSolve[{x*D[f[x], x] + Log[x*s]*f[x] + 1 == 0, f[1] == Exp[-s]},f, x][[1, 1, 2, 2]]
```

[image]

Then make the table and interpolate it:

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{s, sol /. x -> 2}, {s, 0.01, 1, 0.01}], InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

and plot it:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.01, 1}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I'm afraid that $s$ is Integer?

Comment: @Xminer Nothing to be afraid of. Just take those its values you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
eqn = {x*D[f[x], x] + Log[x*s]*f[x] + 1 == 0, f[1] == Exp[-s]};
```

The example can be solved exactly with [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
sol = DSolve[eqn, f, x][[1]]

(* {f -> Function[{x}, 
   1/2 E^(-s - 
     1/2 Log[s x]^2) (2 E^(Log[s]^2/2) + 
      E^s Sqrt[2 π] Erfi[Log[s]/Sqrt[2]] - 
      E^s Sqrt[2 π] Erfi[Log[s x]/Sqrt[2]])]} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
And @@ eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

For a table of the exact solutions for integer values of `s`:

```
Grid[
 Prepend[
  {#, f[x] /. sol /. s -> #} & /@ Range[4] // FullSimplify,
  Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {s, f[x]}],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

For a [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) for integer values of `s`

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[f[x] /. sol, s], {s, 1, 5}],
 {x, 1, 2},
 PlotLegends -> Range[5]]
```

[image]

Or plot in 3D

```
Show[
 Plot3D[f[x] /. sol, {x, 1, 2}, {s, 1, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25]],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate@
   Table[{x, s, f[x] /. sol}, {s, 1, 5}],
  {x, 1, 2}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, s, f}),
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

For a numeric approach use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) or [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)

```
fp = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqn, f, {x, 1, 2}, {s}];
```

In 2 D

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[fp[s][x], s], {s, 1, 5}],
 {x, 1, 2},
 PlotLegends -> Range[5]]
```

Or in 3D

```
Show[
 Plot3D[
  fp[s][x], {x, 1, 2}, {s, 1, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25]],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate@Table[{x, s, fp[s][x]}, {s, 1, 5}],
  {x, 1, 2}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, s, f}),
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ParametricNDSolve`

```
F = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x*D[f[x], x] +Log[x*s]*f[x] + 1 == 0,f[1] == Exp[-s]}, f, {x, 1, 2}, s]
```

which returns a function `F[s][x]` .

`F[s]}[2]` is the function you're looking for

```
Plot[F[s][2], {s, 1, 100}]
```

[image]